# Refugee Travel Document visa-free countries

Tags: refugees

I am a Syrian national, but I have a Canadian refugee travel (1950 Convention) document. I have a few questions.

1. Am I legally allowed to enter Saudi Arabia with the document albeit with a visa?
2. Which countries in Europe besides Germany am I allowed to enter without a visa using the travel document?

Please let me know and if you have additional information also let me know.

Comment: _1951_ Convention. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Front_cover_of_a_Canadian_travel_document_issued_to_refugees_under_the_1951_convention.jpg/220px-Front_cover_of_a_Canadian_travel_document_issued_to_refugees_under_the_1951_convention.jpg Or do you have something else?

Comment: This question is, unfortunately, too broad. Based on [United's Timatic interface](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC), I think you need a visa.